# C++ How to use BlackBerrys MessageService filter API?

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

How does one use the MessageFilter API in BlackBerry 10?

I have this so far;

```
        bb::pim::message::MessageFilter filter;
  //  filter.Participants.QString("XXXXX3");
    filter.insert(bb::pim::message::MessageFilter::Participants, "XXXXXXX");
   QList<bb::pim::message::Conversation> convos = messageService.conversations(smsAccountId,filter);
```

Not sure if its right though?

Thanks

Comment: please ask your query clearly. how you want to filter messages

Comment: Your method correctly filters the messages. You should look into using `ConversationKeys` though. That would cost you less memory